# OpenAPI Yaml how to define Enum inheritance

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm working on a Springboot REST API designed in yaml file as follow.

```
/controller/myApi:
post:
  tags:
    - ... 
  operationId: postNewStudent            
    
  requestBody:
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:              
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/StudentDto'          

components:
  schemas:
    StudentDto:
      type: object
      properties:
        prop1:
          type: string          
        prop2:                   
        studentType:
          $ref: 'common\studentSchema.yaml#/components/schemas/studentType'
```

In my studentSchema.yaml file, the studentType is defined as follow

```
  studentType:
    type: string
    description: |
      ....          
    oneOf: 
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/studentType1'                    
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/studentType2'

  studentType1:
    type: string
    description: ...
    enum: 
     - ENUM_VAL1_1
     - ENUM_VAL1_2
  
  studentType2:
    type: string
    description: ...
    enum:
     - ENUM_VAL2_1
     - ENUM_VAL2_2
```

The Problem here is that my StudentType.java is generated as an interface and cannot be accepted as part of StudentDto. While trying to call the API,  i receive the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `...StudentDto` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer
```

How can i achieve this hierarchy between StudentType, StudentType1 and StudentType2.
(one of the requirements is to give the possibility on Swagger Ui, to see StudentType1 and StudentType2 as subType of StudentType in the StudentDto schema)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed up the OAS description and the schema file but without seeing your Java code, it's difficult to help you further.
The ability for the referenced schema to be resolved depends on the implementation used.

You definitely should not be using `$ref: common\studentSchema.yaml#/components/schemas/studentType` for a few reasons. The main one is `components` is not a JSON Schema keyword, and this keyword is not even present in your `studentSchema.yaml` so it would never resolve, anyway.

The path of `common\studentSchema.yaml` totally depends on how your implementation is able to read that file location. I used `../common` as a placeholder to indicate this is a relative reference.

```yaml
#openapi.yaml


components:
  schemas:
    StudentDto:
      type: object
      properties:
        prop1:
          type: string          
        studentType:
          $ref: '../common/studentSchema.yaml`
```

```yaml
#studentSchema.yaml

$schema: http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#
type: object
required:
  - studentType
additionalProperties: false
properties:
  studentType:
    description: ""
    type: string
    oneOf:
      - $ref: "#/$defs/studentType1"
      - $ref: "#/$defs/studentType2"
    example: DSCHM
$defs:
  studentType1:
    type: string
    description: ...
    enum:
      - ENUM_VAL1_1
      - ENUM_VAL1_2
  studentType2:
    type: string
    description: ...
    enum:
      - ENUM_VAL2_1
      - ENUM_VAL2_2
```